# Getting wrong character encoding when importing .sql to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, character-encoding

I'm importing a large .sql data set to postgresql using this commandline:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -q -f C:\andb\pgrouting\osm2po-5.0.0\dk\dk_2po_4pgr.sql
```

I'm getting the table in my database, but the strings are not able to show 'æ', 'ø' and 'å' correct. When i'm looking in my .sql file these characters are showing. e.g.

```
.sql:       "Pærevænget"
postgresql: "PÃ¦revÃ¦nget"
```

Is there a way to get the right character encoding, when importing a .sql to postgresql?

(I don't have this problem with other tables in my database imported using other methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new database is created, postgresql actually copy the database template1 which is provided by defaults.

This means that when you create a database from your dump postgresql will take the encoding of the template1 database, unless you tell him not to, and this is probably your problem.

A solution for this is to create your database this way (replace you_db_name with the actual name of your database):

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d template1 -c "CREATE DATABASE your_db_name WITH OWNER postgres ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE template0"
```

Using template0 allow you to start from a 'virgin' database and set the encoding yourself. With this you database will use UTF-8 encoding which the most standard and should work with the characters giving you trouble. 
Then you can proceed with your backup but instead of using postgres database use the one you created before :

```
 psql -h localhost -U postgres -d your_db_name -q -f C:\andb\pgrouting\osm2po-5.0.0\dk\dk_2po_4pgr.sql
```

Hope that helps !

Edit :

Reference for the template part : [Postgresql templates](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

You can use `psql -l` to see the list of database including their encoding !